# Is it true or false ? (2-connected graph)

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a $2$-connected graph and $C$ be a smallest cycle in $G$. If $G$ is not a complete graph and a cycle, then there is a path from $x$ to $y$ for some $x,y\in V(C)$ where each vertex in this path is not in $V(C)-\{x,y\}$.I think, this statement holds.

Comment: As stated, this proposition is trivial. We can just take $x$ and $y$ to be adjacent in $C$. Then $x-y$ is certainly a path which is vertex disjoint from $V(C)\backslash\{x,y\}$. You probably want some edge disjointness condition too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it is true.

We take the cycle $C$ and choose a vertex $x$ of degree $\geq 3$ (which exists, since the graph is $2$-connected and is not itself a cycle).  We inspect the paths that start at $x$, avoid $C$ except for its terminal vertices, and terminate at a vertex in $C$.

If there are no such paths, or all such paths would return to $x$, then $x$ is a cut vertex and the graph is not $2$-connected.  So, there is some such path that ends at a vertex other than $x$, and this is our $y$.